# If $A =\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $AB = I$ find the $3\times 2$ matrix $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Alright so you multiply $A$ and $B$ and you get four equations. Then you do $\det[AB] = \det[I] = 1$ and you get a fifth. I'm stuck here now. What else can I do to find $B$?

I'm trying to get this result:

[image]

$$\mathbf B=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
-a-1 & 1-b\\
a+1 & b
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I don't see how the $\det$ part gives you an equation. The determinant of a non-square matrix is $0$. What you have is a linear system of four equations with six variables. You need to find **A** solution (it is not unique).

Comment: It's doable with Gauss elimination and parameters, yes? However, I'm not allowed to use it yet. And you are right, I was wrong about $det$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a general $3\times 2$ matrix
$B=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
e & f
\end{pmatrix}$. Now you require
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
e & f
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

which gives you the set of four equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
-a+e=1\\
c+e=0\\
-b+f=0\\
d+f=1
\end{cases}.
$$

So the first equation says $e=1+a$, the second says $c=-e$, and plugging in the first equality you get $c=-e=-1-a$. Similarly you get $f=b$ from the third equation, and $d=1-f=1-b$ from the third and fourth equations. Thus you obtain that
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
e & f
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
-1-a & 1-b\\
1+a & b
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Oh. Yeah for some reason I didn't think about doing that because I didn't know the answer. I thought I had to find a matrix with no parameters. I posted the screenshot after I checked the answers. This clears it up though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$
B = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
-1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

When you set

$$
B = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
e & f
\end{array}
\right)
$$

You get

$$
A B =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
e-a & f-b\\
c+e & d+f\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

So

$$
e-a=1, f-b=0,c+e=0, d+f=1
$$

Thus we can write

$$
B = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
-1-a & 1-b\\
1+a & b
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Simplest case is $a=0$, $b=0$.

---

General case

$$
B = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
-1 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) + a
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
-1 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) + b
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
0 & -1\\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Yes - it was posted before I finished it... Sorry for that...

Answer (score 2):

Just consider for instance the matrix
$$B=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}-1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{array}\right)\,.$$
Actually, you have 4 equations and 6 coefficients. There are plenty of solutions depending on 2 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to resort to using tons of unknowns in a big linear system. It is very easy to do by inspection.

The first column of B creates a linear combination of the columns of A which is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. This can be done in multiple ways. Some examples are : $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

The same can be done for the second column trying to get a linear combination that makes $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

---

You can actually consider this as solving the system of $6$ unknowns. In effect what you're doing is considering two smaller systems with three unknowns. The fact that there are "not enough equations" is only a problem if you seek a unique solution: if you don't care about that, then it's a boon because it says there are many solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

If you denote the rows of the matrix $B$ as $\vec\alpha$, $\vec\beta$ and $\vec\gamma$, i.e.,
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
\vec\alpha\\\vec\beta\\\vec\gamma
\end{pmatrix},$$
then you can rewrite your equation as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\vec\alpha\\\vec\beta\\\vec\gamma
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\vec\alpha+\vec\gamma\\
\vec\beta+\vec\gamma
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}\vec e_1\\\vec e_2\end{pmatrix}
$$

So you get two equations
$$
\begin{align*}
-\vec\alpha+\vec\gamma&=\vec e_1\\
\vec\beta+\vec\gamma&=\vec e_2
\end{align*}
$$
which leads to
$$
\begin{align*}
\vec\alpha&=\vec\gamma-\vec e_1\\
\vec\beta&=\vec e_2-\vec\gamma&
\end{align*}
$$
If I denote $\vec\gamma=(x,y)$, then the result is
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
\vec\alpha\\\vec\beta\\\vec\gamma
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
x-1 & y\\
-x & 1-y\\
x & y
\end{pmatrix}.$$
After the substitution $x=a+1$, this is the same solution as you have given in your post.